# Is the quotient $SU(4)/SU(2)$ a well known manifold?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, group-actions

Consider the left multiplication action of $SU(2)$ on $SU(4)$. My questions are: is $SU(2)$ a normal subgroup of $SU(4)?$ What is the quotient $SU(4)/SU(2)$? Is this a well known manifold?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it is an $S^5$ bundle over $S^7$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, how did you figure out this? I was exception an answer like that

Comment: Because $SU(2)\to SU(3)\to SU(4)$ we know $SU(4)/SU(2)$ is an $SU(3)/SU(2)$-bundle over $SU(4)/SU(3)$. The fibration $SU(4)/SU(2)\to SU(4)/SU(3)$ is what you think it is, and $SU(n)/SU(n-1)\simeq S^{2n-1}$ by orbit-stabilizer. Note also $SU(4)/S(U(2)^2)$ is a complex Grassmanian and $SU(4)/SU(2)^2$ is the unit tangent bundle $UTS^5$. Plus, $SU(4)$ and $SU(2)$ are the double covers of $SO(6)$ and $SO(3)$ so I expect $SU(4)/SU(2)$ is the same as $SO(6)/SO(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

These are examples of **coset manifolds** 
actually $SU(2)$  is normal subgroup is not required, 
like you can construct $SO(3) /SO(2)$ which is just $S^2$.

If you ask how to calculate metric connection and scaler curvature etc. You can find in
Arvanitoyeorgos - Intr to lie group and the geometry of homogeneous spaces
Page 84 has example of the $S^2$ I talked about.

Hope this helps.

`

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE and thank you for your answer. By the way, if you want to type equations, you can use [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). It might also be interesting to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and to see the [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Sure I was using mobile so did not do the Latex later in I will do.

Comment: @halfbloodprince, thanks for the answer, I am familiar with homogeneous spaces and its curvatures. I am in particular interested about this quotient, on recognizing it as some manifold, even if as a total space of a bundle, so I cannot accept your answer.

Comment: OK sorry no that is the part I am not familiar about sorry I misinterpreted the question.